# Svc file works without codebehind?

Tags: c#, wcf, svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="FirstWcfService.Service1"%>
```

Im hosting my service at WAS using SVC file:

[image]

But as you can see it doesnt have CodeBehind Attrbiute as it should. and its working.

How is that ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx

Comment: It might have been useful for you to say something about the other projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service class is compiled into one of the referenced assemblies. The service used is `FirstWcfService.Service1` as defined in the svc file:

```
Service="FirstWcfService.Service1"
```

CodeBehind only matters to the tooling (Visual Studio). It doesn't matter at runtime, where the system will only look at what types are declared and used.